# Using a fake salt to thwart brute force attacks

Tags: php, security, brute-force

Working on a php login script and want to avoid Captcha, and challenge questions. I was thinking about implementing a ID#, ID and password login prompt.

All users already have a state license number assigned to them and I was thinking about using those numbers for a two-factor authentication.  If they enter a license number and login ID that didn't match, they get a fake salt and automatically fail the password check.

All brute force attempts for the ID and password would fail but the bot wouldn't know why. The bot would have to match a real ID# with a real ID before getting a real salt and a chance at attacking the Password. The only vulnerability I see would be if they knew one of the users, and discovered their license number.  However, if they didn't know the ID, they still wouldn't have a chance.  After 5 failed attempts to login with a real ID and ID# and bad password the account would lock or I would add delays into the process.

Is this idea worth pursuing and what about the countermeasures I suggested?  Thoughts?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could use the `honeypot` method as well. Put a <input type="hidden" name="honeypot"> form input field. On the post submission, if that `hidden` field has a value, you know its a BOT, and ignore the post. Unless the BOT is smart enough to look for <input> attributes, but they just scrape for <input> fields and submit the form usually.

Comment: Do you really think people are more comfortable putting in their driver's license number than doing a captcha field? Epic fail.

Comment: How public is that state license number? Is it something that's available from other sites?

Comment: "Working on a php LOGIN script and want to avoid Captcha, and challenge questions."  Wait, this is for a login script?  I've never seen a login page even bother with captchas or such like. For a login page just block the ip address if its hitting the page over and over fast.

Comment: @developerwjk Really? An abundant amount of login pages revert to a captcha validator on 3+ failed login attempts.

Comment: @Rottingham, well that makes more sense. I thought he meant like having a captcha on the first attempt.

Comment: @developerwjk except when they have a large amount of IP's and switch over before reach a considerable level of alarm which allows them to keep rotating over and over till it finds something of interest.

Comment: No. This is a bad idea in so many ways I'm not even going to bother trying to pick the top two. If you really want to hear all the ways in which this is a terrible idea post the question on security.stackexchange.com like @FabrícioMatté suggested.

Comment: Note that the "fake salt" is irrelevant here, and this is not 2-factor authentication. All you're actually saying is that the user's login credentials consist of 3 parts, which must match, but they're all just strings memorised by the user or brute-forced by the attacker. 2-factor authentication is when you demand proof of something the user has - a "one-time pad" or challenge-response security token, or a phone receiving messages on their configured number.